# Fabric8: openshift/kubernetes java client, create custom objects like ClusterResourceQuota

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, fabric8, kubernetes-operator

I am working on Kubernetes operator that automatically creates namespaces, labels, annotations... based on CRD.

I am stuck with specific openshift object **ClusterResourceQuota** (quota.openshift.io/v1) which is not exposed by fabric8io-kubernetes-client.

Is there any alternative to create such objects even if loaded from file... ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it via fabric8 kubernetes client. Please checkout : https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/doc/CHEATSHEET.md#customresource-typed-api

Comment: If you don't have types, please checkout typeless API: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/doc/CHEATSHEET.md#customresource-typeless-api

Answer (score 4):

I'm from Fabric8 team. Fabric8 Kubernetes Client supports creating Custom objects in two ways:

- Typed API(requires Custom Resource Model(POJOs) to be provided)
- Typeless API (handles Custom Resource as plain HashMaps)

## Typed API:

Assuming that you already have POJOs for `ClusterResourceQuota` and`ClusterResourceQuotaList`. You can create an instance of kubernetes client for that specific Custom resource like this and use it for your Custom Resource operations:

```java
try (KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {
    // Create ClusterResourceQuota object
    ClusterResourceQuota clusterResourceQuota = getClusterResourceQuota();

    // ClusterResourceQuota Client
    MixedOperation<ClusterResourceQuota, ClusterResourceQuotaList, DoneableClusterResourceQuota, Resource<ClusterResourceQuota, DoneableClusterResourceQuota>> clusterResourceQuotaClient = null;
    CustomResourceDefinitionContext context = new CustomResourceDefinitionContext
            .Builder()
            .withGroup("quota.openshift.io")
            .withKind("ClusterResourceQuota")
            .withName("clusterresourcequota-crd")
            .withPlural("clusterresourcequotas")
            .withScope("Namespaced")
            .withVersion("v1")
            .build();

    // Initializing ClusterResourceQuota Client, POJOs to be provided
    clusterResourceQuotaClient = client.customResources(context, ClusterResourceQuota.class, ClusterResourceQuotaList.class, DoneableClusterResourceQuota.class);
    // Using ClusterResourceQuota Client to create ClusterResourceQuota resource
    clusterResourceQuotaClient.inNamespace("default").createOrReplace(clusterResourceQuota);
}
```

## Typeless API

If you don't have POJOs, you can make use of Fabric8 Kubernetes Client's Raw API for dealing with Custom Resources. Here is how you would do it:

```java
try (KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {
    // Create Custom Resource Context
    CustomResourceDefinitionContext context = new CustomResourceDefinitionContext
            .Builder()
            .withGroup("quota.openshift.io")
            .withKind("ClusterResourceQuota")
            .withName("clusterresourcequota-crd")
            .withPlural("clusterresourcequotas")
            .withScope("Namespaced")
            .withVersion("v1")
            .build();

    // Load from Yaml
    Map<String, Object> clusterResourceQuota = client.customResource(context)
            .load(CustomResourceCreateDemoTypeless.class.getResourceAsStream("/clusterquota-cr.yml"));
    // Create Custom Resource
    client.customResource(context).create("default", clusterResourceQuota);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can also have a look at these blogs for [typed](https://medium.com/@rohaan/handling-kubernetes-custom-resources-in-java-using-fabric8-kubernetes-client-part-2-typed-cc0560d9af0d) and [typeless](https://medium.com/@rohaan/handling-kubernetes-custom-resources-in-java-using-fabric8-kubernetes-client-249c4fe01d27) approaches in detail.

Comment: Just curious, for the `typed` approach, are there any tools to generate the POJOs from the crd? Thanks!

Comment: Umm, I think you can generate go structs from CRD: https://itnext.io/how-to-generate-client-codes-for-kubernetes-custom-resource-definitions-crd-b4b9907769ba . Once you create go struct, you should be able to generate POJOs using kubernetes client pojo generator script: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/tree/master/kubernetes-model-generator

Comment: I started a POC on how to generate POJOs directly from struct by just providing some basic configuration: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/tree/master/kubernetes-model-generator (but it's a WIP)